# How true to reality is the film Queen of the Desert?

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, queen-of-the-desert

[*Queen of the Desert*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_the_Desert_(film)) is a 2015 biographical film about [Gertrude Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertrude_Bell), an Englishwoman who spent most of her life in the Middle East and played a part in the establishment of some Arab states in the early 20th century: more or less a "female Lawrence of Arabia". From Wikipedia it seems that the film received many negative reviews, but due to its slow pacing and uneventfulness rather than lack of realism.

**How accurate is this film as a depiction of the life of the real woman Gertrude Bell?** Is it more or less true to life in what it covers (while obviously missing some parts of her life), or does it make up a lot of stuff out of whole cloth?